# Android Studio Gradle Sync failed: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid

Tags: java, android

As somebody new to android studio, I have been getting this error for the past couple of days: Gradle sync failed: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
Consult IDE log for more details
```

I am having trouble trying to find a solution and most of the solutions that people put in can sometimes be way to confusing. Any help quickly would be great because I really want to explore more but I can't.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to find where did you install the java jdk, in program files you should hace a directory of java and into java there are jre directory